# Passing sqlite response value to jquery function in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, sqlite, cordova

I am working on a phonegap app. I am facing some problem while passing value that I am getting from sqlite DB to jquery function.
I am passing a simple date variable to `onclick = popUP("+date+");`, but on the receiving end I am getting some different value. For example if date contains `2015-02-24` the popUP is receiving `1989`. Here is my code:

```
//function will be called when process succeed
function resultSuccess(tx,response) {

    for(var i=0;i<response.rows.length;i++){ 
         date = response.rows.item(i).ARTI_DATE;

        //alert("Title is : " +response.rows.item(i).ARTI_TITLE +"Date is : "+response.rows.item(i).ARTI_DATE+ "Des is : "+response.rows.item(i).ARTI_DESCRIP);

    var margin = 10;            
    $("#routeContainer").append("<div style = 'margin-left: " + margin + "px;'   class = 'test' id='d"+i+"' onclick='popUp("+date+")'><p style='padding-top: 90px;'><b>Thought for the..</b> <br/>Date: <span id='t"+i+"'>"+date+"</span> </p></div> ");
        $('.test').css('background', 'url(img/thumbs/thought.jpg) no-repeat').height(100).width(100);                   
        //$('.test').append($('<input></input>').attr('id','d'+i).attr('type','hidden').attr('value',date));
    }

}

function popUp(d) { 
      alert("Value is " +d);
      var db = window.openDatabase("DEVICEDATA", "1.0", "Device data", 200000); //will create database DEVICEDATA  
        db.transaction(SelectDesc, resultError, resultSuccess);
}
```

Comment: try this `onclick='popUp(\'"+date+"\')'` added `\'`

Comment: The transaction should not be returning the results, the actual query in `SelectDesc` would produce the result and then callback to `resultSuccess`

Comment: Not able to call the popUp() with this code onclick='popUp(\'"+date+"\')'